# How to get string from each line between specified characters?

Tags: batch-file, substring

I have a text file, which has similar lines, like:

```
what to do: do something; when to do: now
what to do: drink; when to do: always
what to do: eat; when to do: sometimes
what to do: laugh a lot; when to do: always
```

I want a batch script, where I can get all the "`what to do`" strings from each line, so the output would be like:

```
do something
drink
eat
laugh a lot
```

So these words are coming from between "`what to do:` " and "`; when to do`" string in each line. (Or just between "`what to do:` " and "`;`")

Many thanks!

Comment: [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is your friend.

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? Please [edit](http://http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40155169/edit) the post and share your efforts! Otherwise this question is too broad...

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@echo off
 for /f "tokens=2 delims=:;" %%a in (YourFile.txt) do echo %%a
```

If you also need the last element (*now*,*always*,*sometimes*)

```
@echo off
 for /f "tokens=2,4 delims=:;" %%a in (log.txt) do echo %%a -^> %%b
```

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "IFN=myfile.txt"
Set "TTF=what to do: "
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Find "%TTF%"^<%IFN%') Do Call :Sub %%A
Timeout -1 1>Nul
Exit/B

    :Sub
    Set _=%*
    Call Set SFL=%%_:*%TTF%=%%
    Set SFL=%SFL:; =&:%
    Echo=%SFL%
```

Make your appropriate changes only on lines two and three, noting in this case the important space at the end of the string on line three.